# What is the required alignment of long double in 64-bit linux, mac, and others?

Tags: linux, macos, gcc, memory-alignment

I have been trying to find out exactly what is the required alignment of long double in x86-64 mac and linux. I have found various different things that hint at different requirements, but can't find an authorative source.

I am finding on Mac OS X, gcc will generate code sometimes which copy long doubles using movaps, which requires 16-byte alignment. But clang does not and gcc is very old, so maybe this is just an old bug which is not going to get fixed?

Comment: With GCC, you could use its `alignof` or `__alignof__` syntactic extension, e.g. `alignof(long double)`; and you could update your GCC, perhaps by compiling GCC 4.7 from its source code.

Comment: For the most part, alignment requirements have nothing to do with the OS a system is running. Alignment is primarily required by the underlying hardware (CPU). In this case, you mention x86-64, which is capable of supporting misaligned loads/stores (but there's a performance penalty) for many general purpose instructions (but SSE/MMX and certain other instructions do actually require proper alignment). The recommended alignment for 64-bit doubles is 64-bit (8 byte).

Comment: I think that on PowerPC-s, the alignment may slightly change with the ABI conventions (some ABI conventions require that stack frames be 16 bytes aligned, other only 8 bytes aligned, all this on the same processor).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Linux x86_64 ABI specifies that long double shall be 16 byte aligned. This is different from the 32-bit x86 Linux ABI, which specifies that long double is only 4 byte aligned (suboptimal on current CPU's but an historical artifact).

I'm not sure about the Mac OSX x86 ABI, but it would surprise me if they'd retain such historical baggage. Hence my guess would be 16-byte alignment.

Comment: So does this mean that gcc is allowed to generate code which will crash if my long doubles are not 16 byte aligned? (which it seems to in gcc 4.2.1, but not 4.6, but that might just be luck of how it chose to optimise)